# How to dispatch Kernel to AMD integrated GPU?

Tags: assembly, gpu, hardware-acceleration, amd-gpu

AMD provides lots of ressources regarding what instructions can be run on their integrated GPUs:
http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2013/12/AMD_GCN3_Instruction_Set_Architecture_rev1.1.pdf

However they do not explain how to dispatch Kernels to the GPU in the first place.
How does that work?
Is it done by assembly instructions, or by some driver controlled through a library?

In short: What would an assembly-only Hello World for an AMD GPU look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In broad terms you'd allocate some memory on the GPU's RAM, load the program binary to it and then issue an execution command to the GPU. The details of those operations are subject of the GPU driver and are exposed toward user space through APIs like OpenCL or Vulkan Compute, where instead of the raw GPU specific instructions a machine independent representation (think like Java binaries) is compiled to GPU instructions in-situ by a Just In Time compiler.

The most elegant approach of course would be heterogenous, fat binaries, where the OS takes care of the details, and you'd issue a kernel execution by calling a trampoline function – this is in fact how CUDA does it. Unfortunately CUDA isn't open source.

However the drivers for AMD GPUs *are* open source, so if you want to get into the gory details of how this actually works down at the lowest levels, your best bet would probably reading the source code of the GCN drivers that are part of Mesa, specifically their implementation of Vulkan compute and OpenCL.

The shortest "Hello GPU" program would either be:

- if you want to use the "regular" drivers, a simple OpenCL or Vulkan compute program.
- if you want to do everything yourself: Implementing the whole of what Mesa does for basic infrastructure support of GCN3, plus a minimal frontend that uses that to load the binary and dispatch the execution.

Comment: Is there an API for loading "gpu assembly"? because OpenCL and stuff seems nice, but rather C-like than assembly-like... How would you (in any way) load amd gpu assembly on the gpu?

Comment: Is this JIT compiler part of the open source driver?

Comment: Here they talk about the kernel part of the AMD Open Source drivers: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=24748488 It is only part of the complete open source package from AMD https://github.com/GPUOpen-Drivers/AMDVLK But the kernel module part alone has 2.7 million lines of code, 1.8 million lines of code headers and 365 thousand lines of C code. Lots of the header code define GPU registers for different graphics card versions, which have to be set up correctly to amoung other things execute GPU assembly.

Comment: But perhaps you want to introduce code before. Here is an overview: https://github.com/GPUOpen-Drivers/llpc/blob/dev/llpc/docs/LlpcOverview.md You find the location of the LLPC in the diagram in the previous comment.

Comment: @Sebastian: At least for the Mesa implementation of Vulkan it is. More specifically it's LLVM, ingesting SPIR-V and emitting GPU native instructions. Then the rest of Mesa is choreographing the whole dance of loading it to the GPU and dispatching the execution.

Comment: @KGM: There's no official API for loading native GPU binaries. However OpenGL (not to be confused with OpenCL), does provide a mechanism to retrieve the result of shader compilation for caching (`glGetProgramBinary`) and so far these binaries were in fact the native GPU code, with some annotations. Vulkan is a little bit more elaborate, as with that API you're caching the whole "pipeline" `vkGetPipelineCacheData`. – In theory you could use those APIs to hack some mechanism to coax a custom GPU binary into the system.

Comment: @KGM: However quite honestly, my recommendation is – unless you're a driver implementor – to treat the GPU as a black box, wrapped into a JIT. If you want to work with assembler-ish code, have a look at SPIR-V. SPIR-V itself is most definitely not GPU native, but its concepts are heavily influenced (albeit I do know more than a few developers, who's prefer to work with GCN3 native rather than SPIR-V in their projects).

Comment: OpenCL with SPIR-V is indeed an attractive option... assembler-ish code would be enough for me.
However i do not understand how this SPIR-V is written and executed either...

Comment: This looks like a newer instruction set: https://developer.amd.com/wp-content/resources/Vega_7nm_Shader_ISA.pdf https://llvm.org/docs/AMDGPUUsage.html The AMDGPU backend of llvm seems to have an assembler integrated "AMDGPU backend has LLVM-MC based assembler which is currently in development. It supports AMDGCN GFX6-GFX11."